# Trigger which check the current Date with the Date in the table

Tags: sql, date, triggers

I do not know how to compare 2 Dates in a trigger (one in the table and the current Date)

Here is my draft of the trigger:

```
CREATE trigger check_update
BEFORE DELETE ON customer_contract
For each row
Begin
If(date_to_cancel_contract > (<date>))
Signal sqlstate ‘45000’
Set message_text = ‘Error, not allowed to cancel contract.’
END IF
```

What’s wrong? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be (provided it is SQL Server)

```
If(date_to_cancel_contract > dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0))
```

Comment: Did you get an error? what is the datatype of the column?